# Heroku compiled slug size is too large but can't find large files

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

I'm trying to build a Python app (using streamlit) and getting

`Compiled slug size: 664M is too large (max is 500M).`

However, when I run

```
heroku run bash -a pitchcast
$ du -ha --max-depth 1 /app
```

the only thing that shows up is

```
4.0K    /app
```

Where are the large files and what can I do to reduce them?

Comment: Surely you're looking at a previous version of the app, as the one that was too big to be deployed was too big to be deployed.

Comment: How can I view the current version/the files that are too big to deploy?

Comment: For more context, the size of the entire directory is just 207M, so I'm confused where the 664M is coming from @jonrsharpe

Comment: @DanielFriedman, the slug includes Python itself and all of your dependencies as well. Do you have dependencies that could cause a problem? Machine learning libraries can be quite big, for example, and it looks like you're using some.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, yep looks like switching from `tensorflow` to `tensorflow-cpu` did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: it seems like the size was due to the Python libraries, especially `tensorflow`. Switching from `tensorflow` to `tensorflow-cpu` got it under 500M